# Display nth letter

Tags: python, awk, sed

How can i display nth letter in a file?

For example,

```
 ABCDEF
```

If I want to see 5th letter

the output would be

```
 E
```

I appreciate for help.

Comment: have you looked into any tutorials or do you have any code to show?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad: do you need help opening the file? reading a particular value from that file? outputting a character you have read?

Comment: Here is one way: `echo "ABCDEF" | awk '{print substr($0,5,1)}'`

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with `python`, `awk` and `sed` when all you need for this is `cut` ...

```
$ echo 'ABCDEF' | cut -c5
E
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def myRead(infilepath, n):
    with open(infilepath) as infile:
        infile.seek(n-1)
        return infile.read(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

using `grep`:

```
 echo "ABCDE" | grep -o "\w$"
 #  if anything on last use this echo "ABCDE" | grep -o ".$"
```

output:

```
E
```

using `python`:

```
>>> "ABCDE"[-1]
'E'
```

using awk:

```
 echo "ABCDE" | awk '{print substr($0,length($0))}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dd`

```
dd if=file bs=1 count=1 iseek=5 2>/dev/null
```

Your `dd` may use `skip` instead of `iseek`.